# How do I share access with my entire organization to a SNS Topic?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-sns

I'm trying to set up a single SNS Topic that can be used by all AWS accounts within our organization. I have created these accounts through the organization and can see they are tied to the organization.

I'm probably missing something obvious, but I can't figure out why these permissions are not working.

For this example, my organization id is "o-1234567890" and ARN is "arn:aws:sns:us-east-2:123456123456:ARN-NAME"

Here is what we have for our policy:

```
{
  "Version": "2008-10-17",
  "Id": "__default_policy_ID",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
      },
      "Action": "SNS:Publish",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-2:123456123456:ARN-NAME",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "aws:PrincipalOrgID": "o-1234567890"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Attempting to configure the SNS topic on the "child" account does not work, even though it belongs to the above organization.

We get the error:

**An invalid or out-of-range value was supplied for the input parameter.**
SNS topic arn:aws:sns:us-east-2:123456123456:ARN-NAME is invalid.

If we update the policy to the following (removing the condition), it works just fine and as expected:

```
{
  "Version": "2008-10-17",
  "Id": "__default_policy_ID",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
      },
      "Action": "SNS:Publish",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-2:123456123456:ARN-NAME"
    }
  ]
}
```

Am I missing something? I'm configuring it exactly like it is in the [AWS documentation here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-access-policy-use-cases.html#sns-allow-organization-to-publish-to-topic-in-another-account).

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing obviously wrong with your policy - you've replicated the example, and your testing approach (removing the condition) is a good one!

Does your Organization [have all features enabled](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/organizations/latest/userguide/orgs_manage_org_support-all-features.html)? That's the only reason I can think that a policy wouldn't allow the `aws:PrincipalOrgID` to be used.

Comment: Unfortunately, our account has "Your organization has all features enabled." turned on.

Thank you for the prompt response though!